# I am getting a database panic: The database has encountered a critical error, and needs to be restarted

Tags: ubuntu, neo4j

We've just launched our new company and I restarted the database server earlier today and got the following log trace.

```
2018-07-13 11:46:22.204+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] --- INITIALIZED diagnostics START ---
2018-07-13 11:46:22.205+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Neo4j Kernel properties:
2018-07-13 11:46:22.205+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
2018-07-13 11:46:22.205+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] dbms.security.auth_enabled=true
2018-07-13 11:46:22.205+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] dbms.windows_service_name=neo4j
2018-07-13 11:46:22.206+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] dbms.connector.https.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7594
2018-07-13 11:46:22.206+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] unsupported.dbms.directories.neo4j_home=/var/lib/neo4j
2018-07-13 11:46:22.206+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7288
2018-07-13 11:46:22.206+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] dbms.directories.import=/var/lib/neo4j/import
2018-07-13 11:46:22.206+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=5g
2018-07-13 11:46:22.206+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] dbms.memory.pagecache.size=9g
2018-07-13 11:46:22.206+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] dbms.directories.data=/var/lib/neo4j/data
2018-07-13 11:46:22.206+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] dbms.directories.run=/var/run/neo4j
2018-07-13 11:46:22.206+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] dbms.directories.lib=/usr/share/neo4j/lib
2018-07-13 11:46:22.206+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] unsupported.dbms.edition=community
2018-07-13 11:46:22.207+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] dbms.directories.logs=/var/log/neo4j
2018-07-13 11:46:22.207+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
2018-07-13 11:46:22.207+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] dbms.directories.certificates=/var/lib/neo4j/certificates
2018-07-13 11:46:22.207+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
2018-07-13 11:46:22.207+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] dbms.jvm.additional=-Dunsupported.dbms.udc.source=debian
2018-07-13 11:46:22.207+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] dbms.directories.plugins=/var/lib/neo4j/plugins
2018-07-13 11:46:22.207+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy=1 days
2018-07-13 11:46:22.207+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] dbms.memory.heap.max_size=5g
2018-07-13 11:46:22.207+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Diagnostics providers:
2018-07-13 11:46:22.208+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Config
2018-07-13 11:46:22.208+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] org.neo4j.kernel.info.DiagnosticsManager
2018-07-13 11:46:22.208+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] SYSTEM_MEMORY
2018-07-13 11:46:22.208+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] JAVA_MEMORY
2018-07-13 11:46:22.208+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] OPERATING_SYSTEM
2018-07-13 11:46:22.208+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] JAVA_VIRTUAL_MACHINE
2018-07-13 11:46:22.208+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] CLASSPATH
2018-07-13 11:46:22.208+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] LIBRARY_PATH
2018-07-13 11:46:22.208+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] SYSTEM_PROPERTIES
2018-07-13 11:46:22.208+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] LINUX_SCHEDULERS
2018-07-13 11:46:22.208+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] NETWORK
2018-07-13 11:46:22.209+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] System memory information:
2018-07-13 11:46:22.212+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Total Physical memory: 15.67 GB
2018-07-13 11:46:22.212+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Free Physical memory: 9.89 GB
2018-07-13 11:46:22.213+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Committed virtual memory: 8.06 GB
2018-07-13 11:46:22.213+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Total swap space: 0.00 B
2018-07-13 11:46:22.213+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Free swap space: 0.00 B
2018-07-13 11:46:22.213+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] JVM memory information:
2018-07-13 11:46:22.213+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Free  memory: 4.92 GB
2018-07-13 11:46:22.213+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Total memory: 5.00 GB
2018-07-13 11:46:22.213+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Max   memory: 5.00 GB
2018-07-13 11:46:22.215+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Garbage Collector: G1 Young Generation: [G1 Eden Space, G1 Survivor Space]
2018-07-13 11:46:22.215+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Garbage Collector: G1 Old Generation: [G1 Eden Space, G1 Survivor Space, G1 Old Gen]
2018-07-13 11:46:22.215+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Memory Pool: Code Cache (Non-heap memory): committed=5.06 MB, used=5.01 MB, max=240.00 MB, threshold=0.00 B
2018-07-13 11:46:22.216+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Memory Pool: Metaspace (Non-heap memory): committed=13.63 MB, used=12.71 MB, max=-1.00 B, threshold=0.00 B
2018-07-13 11:46:22.216+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Memory Pool: Compressed Class Space (Non-heap memory): committed=1.88 MB, used=1.65 MB, max=1.00 GB, threshold=0.00 B
2018-07-13 11:46:22.216+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Memory Pool: G1 Eden Space (Heap memory): committed=270.00 MB, used=76.00 MB, max=-1.00 B, threshold=?
2018-07-13 11:46:22.216+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Memory Pool: G1 Survivor Space (Heap memory): committed=0.00 B, used=0.00 B, max=-1.00 B, threshold=?
2018-07-13 11:46:22.216+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Memory Pool: G1 Old Gen (Heap memory): committed=4.74 GB, used=0.00 B, max=5.00 GB, threshold=0.00 B
2018-07-13 11:46:22.216+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Operating system information:
2018-07-13 11:46:22.217+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Operating System: Linux; version: 4.4.0-1062-aws; arch: amd64; cpus: 4
2018-07-13 11:46:22.217+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Max number of file descriptors: 60000
2018-07-13 11:46:22.217+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Number of open file descriptors: 110
2018-07-13 11:46:22.225+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Process id: 19097@ip-172-31-24-163
2018-07-13 11:46:22.225+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Byte order: LITTLE_ENDIAN
2018-07-13 11:46:22.231+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Local timezone: Etc/UTC
2018-07-13 11:46:22.231+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] JVM information:
2018-07-13 11:46:22.231+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] VM Name: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
2018-07-13 11:46:22.232+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] VM Vendor: Oracle Corporation
2018-07-13 11:46:22.232+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] VM Version: 25.171-b11
2018-07-13 11:46:22.232+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] JIT compiler: HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
2018-07-13 11:46:22.232+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] VM Arguments: [-Xms5g, -Xmx5g, -XX:+UseG1GC, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions, -XX:+TrustFinalNonStaticFields, -XX:+DisableExplicitGC, -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048, -Dunsupported.dbms.udc.source=debian, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8]
2018-07-13 11:46:22.232+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Java classpath:
.......
2018-07-13 11:46:22.239+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64
2018-07-13 11:46:22.240+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni
2018-07-13 11:46:22.240+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
2018-07-13 11:46:22.240+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
2018-07-13 11:46:22.240+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] /usr/lib/jni
2018-07-13 11:46:22.240+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] /lib
2018-07-13 11:46:22.240+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] /usr/lib
2018-07-13 11:46:22.240+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] System.properties:
2018-07-13 11:46:22.240+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] sun.boot.library.path = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64
2018-07-13 11:46:22.240+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] path.separator = :
2018-07-13 11:46:22.240+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] file.encoding.pkg = sun.io
2018-07-13 11:46:22.240+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] user.country = US
2018-07-13 11:46:22.240+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD
2018-07-13 11:46:22.240+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] sun.os.patch.level = unknown
2018-07-13 11:46:22.241+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] user.dir = /
2018-07-13 11:46:22.241+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] sun.jnu.encoding = UTF-8
2018-07-13 11:46:22.241+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] unsupported.dbms.udc.source = debian
2018-07-13 11:46:22.241+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] sun.management.compiler = HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
2018-07-13 11:46:22.241+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] user.home = /var/lib/neo4j
2018-07-13 11:46:22.241+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] user.timezone = Etc/UTC
2018-07-13 11:46:22.241+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] file.encoding = UTF-8
2018-07-13 11:46:22.241+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] user.name = neo4j
2018-07-13 11:46:22.241+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] sun.java.command = org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint --home-dir=/var/lib/neo4j --config-dir=/etc/neo4j
2018-07-13 11:46:22.241+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] sun.arch.data.model = 64
2018-07-13 11:46:22.241+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] user.language = en
2018-07-13 11:46:22.241+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] awt.toolkit = sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
2018-07-13 11:46:22.241+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] jdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize = 2048
2018-07-13 11:46:22.241+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] file.separator = /
2018-07-13 11:46:22.241+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle
2018-07-13 11:46:22.241+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] sun.cpu.endian = little
2018-07-13 11:46:22.241+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] sun.cpu.isalist = 
2018-07-13 11:46:22.241+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Linux scheduler information:
2018-07-13 11:46:22.246+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] none
....
2018-07-13 11:46:22.251+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] none
2018-07-13 11:46:22.251+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Network information:
2018-07-13 11:46:22.252+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface eth0:
2018-07-13 11:46:22.252+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]     address: fe80:0:0:0:4d8:83ff:fe41:b7cc%eth0
2018-07-13 11:46:22.252+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]     address: 172.31.24.163
2018-07-13 11:46:22.253+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] Interface lo:
2018-07-13 11:46:22.253+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]     address: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo
2018-07-13 11:46:22.253+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]     address: 127.0.0.1
2018-07-13 11:46:22.253+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] --- INITIALIZED diagnostics END ---
2018-07-13 11:46:22.395+0000 INFO [o.n.b.v.r.WorkerFactory] Bolt Server extension loaded.
2018-07-13 11:46:22.395+0000 INFO [o.n.b.v.r.WorkerFactory] Bolt enabled on 0.0.0.0:7288.
2018-07-13 11:46:22.651+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.s.f.RecordFormatSelector] Selected RecordFormat:StandardV3_2[v0.A.8] record format from store /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db
2018-07-13 11:46:22.674+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.s.f.RecordFormatSelector] Selected RecordFormat:StandardV3_2[v0.A.8] record format from store /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db
2018-07-13 11:46:22.674+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.s.f.RecordFormatSelector] Format not configured. Selected format from the store: RecordFormat:StandardV3_2[v0.A.8]
2018-07-13 11:46:23.384+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.a.i.IndexingService] IndexingService.init: indexes not specifically mentioned above are ONLINE
2018-07-13 11:46:23.391+0000 INFO [o.n.k.NeoStoreDataSource] Commits found after last check point (which is at LogPosition{logVersion=89, byteOffset=8450364}). First txId after last checkpoint: 8788240 
2018-07-13 11:46:23.391+0000 INFO [o.n.k.NeoStoreDataSource] Recovery required from position LogPosition{logVersion=89, byteOffset=8450364}
2018-07-13 11:46:23.446+0000 ERROR [o.n.k.i.DatabaseHealth] Database panic: The database has encountered a critical error, and needs to be restarted. Please see database logs for more details. Failed to apply transaction: null
org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.TransactionApplyKernelException: Failed to apply transaction: null
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine.apply(RecordStorageEngine.java:334)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.DefaultRecoverySPI.lambda$getRecoveryApplier$0(DefaultRecoverySPI.java:86)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.TransactionQueue.empty(TransactionQueue.java:68)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.DefaultRecoverySPI$RecoveryVisitor.close(DefaultRecoverySPI.java:143)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.Recovery.init(Recovery.java:133)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:406)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:62)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:98)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:524)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:100)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:207)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:126)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer.lambda$static$0(CommunityNeoServer.java:58)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:88)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:211)
    at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:111)
    at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:79)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:32)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to flush index updates
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.command.IndexBatchTransactionApplier.applyPendingLabelAndIndexUpdates(IndexBatchTransactionApplier.java:103)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.command.IndexBatchTransactionApplier.close(IndexBatchTransactionApplier.java:124)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.BatchTransactionApplierFacade.close(BatchTransactionApplierFacade.java:70)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine.apply(RecordStorageEngine.java:331)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.UnderlyingStorageException: IndexEntryConflictException{propertyValues=( Long(9) ), addedNodeId=12167147, existingNodeId=12156867}
    at org.neo4j.concurrent.WorkSync.checkFailure(WorkSync.java:182)
    at org.neo4j.concurrent.WorkSync.apply(WorkSync.java:91)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.command.IndexBatchTransactionApplier.applyPendingLabelAndIndexUpdates(IndexBatchTransactionApplier.java:99)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.UnderlyingStorageException: IndexEntryConflictException{propertyValues=( Long(9) ), addedNodeId=12167147, existingNodeId=12156867}
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.command.IndexUpdatesWork.apply(IndexUpdatesWork.java:67)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.command.IndexUpdatesWork.apply(IndexUpdatesWork.java:42)
    at org.neo4j.concurrent.WorkSync.doSynchronizedWork(WorkSync.java:231)
    at org.neo4j.concurrent.WorkSync.tryDoWork(WorkSync.java:157)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: IndexEntryConflictException{propertyValues=( Long(9) ), addedNodeId=12167147, existingNodeId=12156867}
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.schema.NativeSchemaNumberIndexUpdater.assertNoConflict(NativeSchemaNumberIndexUpdater.java:148)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.schema.NativeSchemaNumberIndexUpdater.processAdd(NativeSchemaNumberIndexUpdater.java:138)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.schema.NativeSchemaNumberIndexUpdater.processUpdate(NativeSchemaNumberIndexUpdater.java:93)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.schema.NativeSchemaNumberIndexUpdater.process(NativeSchemaNumberIndexUpdater.java:65)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.schema.fusion.FusionIndexUpdater.process(FusionIndexUpdater.java:48)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.IndexingService.processUpdate(IndexingService.java:454)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.IndexingService.apply(IndexingService.java:417)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.IndexingService.apply(IndexingService.java:397)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.command.IndexUpdatesWork.apply(IndexUpdatesWork.java:63)
    ... 31 more
2018-07-13 11:46:23.485+0000 WARN [o.n.k.NeoStoreDataSource] Exception occurred while starting the datasource. Attempting to close things down. Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.Recovery@4038cd3a' failed to initialize. Please see the attached cause exception "Both node 12156867 and node 12167147 share the property value ( Long(9) )".
org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.Recovery@4038cd3a' failed to initialize. Please see the attached cause exception "Both node 12156867 and node 12167147 share the property value ( Long(9) )".
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:427)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:62)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:98)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:524)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:100)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:207)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:126)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer.lambda$static$0(CommunityNeoServer.java:58)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:88)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:211)
    at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:111)
    at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:79)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:32)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.TransactionApplyKernelException: Failed to apply transaction: null
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine.apply(RecordStorageEngine.java:334)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.DefaultRecoverySPI.lambda$getRecoveryApplier$0(DefaultRecoverySPI.java:86)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.TransactionQueue.empty(TransactionQueue.java:68)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.DefaultRecoverySPI$RecoveryVisitor.close(DefaultRecoverySPI.java:143)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.Recovery.init(Recovery.java:133)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:406)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to flush index updates
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.command.IndexBatchTransactionApplier.applyPendingLabelAndIndexUpdates(IndexBatchTransactionApplier.java:103)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.command.IndexBatchTransactionApplier.close(IndexBatchTransactionApplier.java:124)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.BatchTransactionApplierFacade.close(BatchTransactionApplierFacade.java:70)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine.apply(RecordStorageEngine.java:331)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.UnderlyingStorageException: IndexEntryConflictException{propertyValues=( Long(9) ), addedNodeId=12167147, existingNodeId=12156867}
    at org.neo4j.concurrent.WorkSync.checkFailure(WorkSync.java:182)
    at org.neo4j.concurrent.WorkSync.apply(WorkSync.java:91)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.command.IndexBatchTransactionApplier.applyPendingLabelAndIndexUpdates(IndexBatchTransactionApplier.java:99)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.UnderlyingStorageException: IndexEntryConflictException{propertyValues=( Long(9) ), addedNodeId=12167147, existingNodeId=12156867}
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.command.IndexUpdatesWork.apply(IndexUpdatesWork.java:67)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.command.IndexUpdatesWork.apply(IndexUpdatesWork.java:42)
    at org.neo4j.concurrent.WorkSync.doSynchronizedWork(WorkSync.java:231)
    at org.neo4j.concurrent.WorkSync.tryDoWork(WorkSync.java:157)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: IndexEntryConflictException{propertyValues=( Long(9) ), addedNodeId=12167147, existingNodeId=12156867}
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.schema.NativeSchemaNumberIndexUpdater.assertNoConflict(NativeSchemaNumberIndexUpdater.java:148)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.schema.NativeSchemaNumberIndexUpdater.processAdd(NativeSchemaNumberIndexUpdater.java:138)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.schema.NativeSchemaNumberIndexUpdater.processUpdate(NativeSchemaNumberIndexUpdater.java:93)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.schema.NativeSchemaNumberIndexUpdater.process(NativeSchemaNumberIndexUpdater.java:65)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.schema.fusion.FusionIndexUpdater.process(FusionIndexUpdater.java:48)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.IndexingService.processUpdate(IndexingService.java:454)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.IndexingService.apply(IndexingService.java:417)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.IndexingService.apply(IndexingService.java:397)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.command.IndexUpdatesWork.apply(IndexUpdatesWork.java:63)
    ... 31 more
2018-07-13 11:46:23.486+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] --- STOPPING diagnostics START ---
2018-07-13 11:46:23.487+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager] --- STOPPING diagnostics END ---
2018-07-13 11:46:23.487+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.f.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory] Shutdown started
2018-07-13 11:46:25.812+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.f.CommunityEditionModule] No locking implementation specified, defaulting to 'community'
```

It seems that the crucial line here is:

```
Database panic: The database has encountered a critical error, and needs to be restarted. Please see database logs for more details. Failed to apply transaction: null
org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.TransactionApplyKernelException: Failed to apply transaction: null
```

I can't find any information about this though.

Ubuntu server 16.04

Neo4j 3.3.1

RAM 16GB

HDD 16GB

Free space on HDD: 9.4GB

**Memory configuration:**

dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=5g

dbms.memory.heap.max_size=5g

dbms.memory.pagecache.size=9g

**Actual Graph usage** (calcs as per [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.3/performance/memory-configuration/)):

Lucene indexes: 66MB

Page Size: 3.6GB + 3.6GB = 7.2G

The error was happening *before* I set the memory config (before it was default) and is still happening *after* I set the memory config.

I can no longer get any service *at all* from the database as it won't start.  Do I need more memory?  Anything else that I should be considering please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

During the start process, neo4j is trying to apply the last transactions on the file system, and it fails !

Why ? Because you have a problem on your indexes : `IndexEntryConflictException{propertyValues=( Long(9) ), addedNodeId=12167147, existingNodeId=12156867}`

So what you can try is to delete the `index` and `schema` folders, and then start Neo4j.

Comment: You Sir are a HERO.  It worked.  Do you think I am close to the wire with the amount of RAM I have on this instance by the way?  Thank you SO much.  So appreciative right now!

Comment: I take +1 on the answer, its validation, but also beers :)

Comment: for the sizinf, and I don't know, I need the size of your database (`:sysinfo` on the browser)

Comment: Thanks.  I am now getting "Unable to validate constraint Constraint( UNIQUE, :SystemEmail(emailNumber) )" when trying to make an insert.  Do I need to rebuild the indexes or something?  If I do a list of indexes with "CALL db.indexes" they all have status "failed".  Any ideas?  Thanks again!

Comment: Normally Neo4j rebuild indexes at startup if they are not there ... You should check the debug.log file to see if tghere are some errors.  Otherwise you can simply dele all your indexes + constraints, and then recreate them.

Comment: Thanks. No errors in the debug log.  If I try "DROP INDEX ON :SystemEmail(emailNumber)" I get "Unable to drop index on :SystemEmail(emailNumber): Index belongs to constraint: :SystemEmail(emailNumber)".  If I try "DROP CONSTRAINT ON (a:SystemEmail) ASSERT a.emailNumber IS UNIQUE" I get "Neo.ClientError.Transaction.TransactionValidationFailed: Index population failure".  So it seems that I can't now delete the indexes or constraints.  Unless there is a better way?

Comment: I was being dim!  I hadn't STOPPED the neo4j service when I deleted the index and schema folders.  I just stopped it, deleted them again, started it again and all appears to now work :)

Comment: Thanks again.  I've got to go camping now!  Just sorted it in time!  I've marked this as the solution as it worked brilliantly.  Thanks again.  So thankful.

Comment: INFO [o.n.k.i.a.i.IndexingService] IndexingService.init: indexes not specifically mentioned above are POPULATING
Cannot map non-existing file | GBPTree[file:/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/b_a.db/schema/index/lucene_native-2.0/18/native-1.0/index-18     unable to recover from this state.